# Cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewSource?

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on an Ionic Project where i am getting below errors for google maps while building the app.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewSource;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class StreetViewSource
  location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
I:\Team SlowCoach\OfferShare\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
          StreetViewSource source = "OUTDOOR".equals(cameraOpts.getString("source")) ?
          ^
  symbol:   class StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama
I:\Team SlowCoach\OfferShare\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
              ^
  symbol:   variable StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama
I:\Team SlowCoach\OfferShare\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama
I:\Team SlowCoach\OfferShare\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource source = "OUTDOOR".equals(cameraOpts.getString("source")) ?
              ^
  symbol: class StreetViewSource
I:\Team SlowCoach\OfferShare\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                  StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                  ^
  symbol: variable StreetViewSource
I:\Team SlowCoach\OfferShare\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                  StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                                             ^
  symbol: variable StreetViewSource
```

In **package.json**:

```
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.4.6",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.9.1"
```

In **project.properties**:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.+
cordova.gradle.include.1=twitter-connect-plugin/offershare-twitter.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.5=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/offershare-tbxml-android.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+
cordova.system.library.8=com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
```

**Which version of google maps should i use?**

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes. I will update you

Comment: I solved my problem.

Comment: @setu and sudarshan : sir plz tell me how to fixed above error,i tried everything but nothing worked for me.i stuck above error last 2 days.plz tell me how to fix?